# Pass item onPress in for loop to method/function in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using a for loop to loop through categories from an API which works as expected:

```
renderFilter=()=> {
const items = [];
for (item of this.state.newsCats) {
    items.push(
      <TouchableOpacity key={item.module_cat_id} onPress={()=>this.FilterRequest(item.module_cat_id)}><Text style={styles.filterCat}>{item.module_cat} {item.module_cat_id}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
return items;
}
```

FilterRequest fires correctly onPress but it always returns the last module_cat_id in the loop rather than the id of the category selected:

```
FilterRequest = (module_cat_id) => {
console.log(module_cat_id);
this.setState({
  news_cat_id: module_cat_id,
}, () =>{
  this.NewsRequest();
  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
});
}
```

How can I get the correct `item.module_cat_id` into FilterRequest? 
Both code snippets are in the same js file.

Comment: can you share an expo working snack so that i can check there?

Comment: The only thing that seems weird is that you are not declaring the `item` variable in the for of loop inside `renderFilter` method `for (let item of this.state.newsCats)`.

Comment: @GauravRoy unfortunately i can't share a working snack as there are fetch requests and sensitive information i can't share. However i can supply the code with information edited out if that helps?

Comment: @mgarcia - i added let to the for loop and now works. If you make that an answer i'l mark it as correct.

Comment: @S.B, done!. Added answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the declaration of the `item` variable in the for of loop inside `renderFilter` method:

```
renderFilter = () => {
    const items = [];
    for (let item of this.state.newsCats) {
        items.push(
            <TouchableOpacity key={item.module_cat_id} onPress={()=>this.FilterRequest(item.module_cat_id)}><Text style={styles.filterCat}>{item.module_cat} {item.module_cat_id}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
    return items;
}
```